# How can I make visible cursor footprints/ghosts disappear from the command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, memory

That's the problem I'm having while running gdb in cmd under Windows 10.  This isn't a question about gdb usage. The cursor's footprint (when visible) is stamped on each line that's created within gdb in cmd.  Like when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to continue stepping through code... if the cursor is visible during that key press, its footprint is visible on the most recent line that is created.

[image: screenshot of cursor footprints within gdb in cmd]

Is this a memory problem?  Have been working on this for a long time... did I run out of memory? I should have around 6gb of memory available.

Or maybe it has to do with my .bat file, it has:

```
gcc -g myfile.c -o myfile
gdb -q ./myfile
```

Just wondering about the ./ in front of the executable... is the ./ the problem?  Just read somewhere that ./ is important in front of the executable name when running gdb.

How can we make this cursor footprint disappear?  Why does it happen? Thank you for reading. :)

Notes:
-g flag has gcc create debug info for gdb; -o flag lets me specify executable name; -q flag starts gdb quietly

Comment: Your image shows some lines that have ‘‘footprints’’ and some that don’t. What did you do differently?

Comment: @Scott The cursor appears and disappears over and over... I just didn't hold down the <enter> key. :)  (Holding <enter> would make the footprint never change.)

Comment: @JakeGould Thank you so much for teaching me about how to <kbd>enter</kbd> show keyboard keys! :D